# Unwanted copy constructor call when creating a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

While doing some coding practice, I encountered the following error when attempting to pass ownership of an optional `std::unique_ptr` to a `std::shared_ptr`:

```
/usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:162:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Dp = std::default_delete]’
  162 |         { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/memory:76,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_ptr.h:468:7: note: declared here
  468 |       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

This was the particular snippet that resulted in my error (apologies for the nonsensical code):

```
#include <optional>
#include <memory>

class test_class
{
    public:
        struct options
        {
            options();
            std::optional<std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>> data;
        };
    
        test_class(const test_class::options &options = test_class::options());

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>> _data;
};

test_class::test_class(
    const test_class::options &options)
{
    if (options.data.has_value())
    {
        _data = std::make_shared<std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>>(std::move(options.data.value()));
    }
}
```

I assumed that I would've bypassed any copy constructors by using the `std::move` call, but it seems like I may be inadvertently calling it anyway.

Furthermore, I ran this similar snippet of code, but there was no error:

```
test_class::test_class(
    const test_class::options &options)
{
    std::optional<std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>> data;

    if (data.has_value())
    {
        _data = std::make_shared<std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>>(std::move(data.value()));
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Why is the first snippet wrong? Is there some C++ fundamental I am misunderstanding? Why does the second snippet not also fail?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code isn't passing ownership from unique_ptr to shared_ptr, it's creating a shared_ptr of a uniqune_ptr by moving the optional unique_ptr

Comment: `std::make_shared<std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>>` would create a shared_ptr ponting to a unique_ptr. Makes no sense at all...

Comment: Also, instead of an optional unique_ptr, I would just have a unique_ptr holding a nullptr.

Comment: I'm not so much trying to write functional code, but trying to understand the concepts through nonsensical examples. I'm mostly curious why this example isn't working, but why the second snippet works fine. @BoP

Comment: Because it's a `const`. You cannot move out of a `const`.

Comment: You're right about nonsensical code. `uniqe_ptr` does not need `optional`; you can just set `unique_ptr` to `nullptr`. `shared_ptr` to `uniqe_ptr` is also wierd looking. Normally you can just use `shared_ptr`. Double pointers are always fishy.

Comment: My apologies for that. Since I was majorly unaware of what was causing my issue, this was the only isolated snippet I could come up with when trying to replicate its behavior. I appreciate all the feedback, though! @Red.Wave

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI So instead of using all this complicated options and pointers mess we could as well just try to move, say, an int member and it would show the same error?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica An `int` can be copied so it will just fall back on copying. `unique_ptr` is not copyable, that's the reason for the error. Can't move and can't copy.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Ah, ok, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in a comment above, this behavior is a result of the `test_class::options` argument of the constructor being `const`. The use of `std::move` is intended to cast `options.data.value` to a `const std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>&&`. However, due to the const qualifier, it prevents the use of the move constructor. Consequently, the code attempts to construct a new unique_ptr from this casted value but falls back to using the copy constructor instead of the move constructor.

I corrected this as follows:

```
#include <optional>
#include <memory>

class test_class
{
    public:
        struct options
        {
            options();
            
            std::optional<std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>> data;
        };
        
        test_class(test_class::options &&options =  = dst_file::options());

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>> _data;
};

test_class::test_class(
    const test_class::options &options)
{
   
}

test_class::test_class(
    test_class::options &&options)
{
    if (options.data.has_value())
    {
        _data = std::make_shared<std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>>(std::move(options.data.value()));
    }
}
```

Since `test_class::options` is now an "rvalue reference" (as denoted by the `&&`), it will invoke the move constructor by default.

Comment: Can you edit the answer to clarify that:
`std::move` merely casts `options.data.value` to `const std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>&&`, and then the written code tries to construct the new `unique_ptr` from that, but since it's `const` it can't use the move constructor, so is falling back to the copy constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Your complicated nested pointers obscure the underlying issue somewhat. Ownership is not really the issue here, and there is no issue creating a shared_ptr from a unique_ptr. The error you get concerns solely the unique_ptr. Here the mentioned "obscuring" becomes noticeable because the error is hard to understand. But if I cut all the fluff like std:: and template parameters, it boils down to

> use of deleted function unique_ptr::**unique_ptr(const unique_ptr &)**,

which is the copy constructor. The copy constructor for unique_ptr is deleted because a unique_ptr cannot be copied; it is, after all, unique.

But why is the copy constructor selected at all by overload resolution? Because the declared move constructor moves from an rvalue reference which is *not const*. A const rvalue reference is simply not a match. The fallback then is an attempt to use the copy constructor since a const reference can be bound to a constant rvalue reference; but that one is, as we said, deleted for good reasons.

Below is code which demonstrates the workings with a trivial class S. Your constructor case is demonstrated with `test_class`, but the easiest demonstration is actually the last line in `main()`:  You simply cannot construct an `S` from a const rref. The case that an `S` may be a member of a different class and the construction is part of that class's initialization is not really important to the problem.

```
#include <utility> // std::move

using namespace std;

// this takes on the role of unique_ptr in your example
struct S 
{ 
    S() = default;

    // [1] enable the copy constructor ... 
    //S(const S&) = default;

    // [2] ... or the move constructor from rref to const;
    //S(const S&&) {}

    // [3] OR remove the move constructor; that will un-delete the copy ctor
    S(S&&) = default;
};

class test_class
{
    public:
        S _s;
 
        // Does not work because no constructor matches. In the order of 
        // resolution attempts: 
        // 1. The best match, a constructor taking a const rref argument, is not declared, see [2]
        // 2. The declared regular move constructor [3] taking a non-const rref argument does not match;
        // 3. The regular copy constructor taking a const ref argument
        //    is implicitly deleted because we declared a move constructor [3].
        //    We could explicitly define it, [1]
        // test_class(const S &sArg): _s{move(sArg)} {}
 };

int main()
{
    const S cs;
     // move actually works like a charm but produces an rref to const.
    const S &&s_rref{move(cs)};

    // construction from a const rref is not defined.
    // S s{move(cs)};
}
```

[Here is a version on godbolt.](https://www.godbolt.org/z/jKPb1E81o)